# Function service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info() not working

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, oauth-2.0, service-accounts

I'm writing an application based on GCP services and I need to access to an external project. I stored on my Firestore database the authentication file's informations of the other project I need to access to. I read [this documentation](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html#google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info) and I tried to apply it but my code does not work. As the documentaion says, what I pass to the authentication method is a dictionary[str, str].
This is my code:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import firestore

project_id = body['project_id']
user = body['user']
snap_id = body['snapshot_id']
debuggee_id = body['debuggee_id']
db = firestore.Client()
ref = db.collection(u'users').document(user).collection(u'projects').document(project_id)
if ref.get().exists:
    service_account_info = ref.get().to_dict()
else:
    return None, 411

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    service_account_info,
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

service = discovery.build('clouddebugger', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
```

body is just a dictionary containing all the informations of the other project. What I can't understand is why this doesn't work and instead using the method *from_service_account_file* it works.
The following code will give to that method the same informations of the previous code, but inside a json file instead of a dictionary. Maybe the order of the elements is different, but I think that it doesn't matter at all.

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    [PATH_TO_PROJECT_KEY_FILE],
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong with the method *from_service_account_info*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. When I posted the question I manually inserted from the GCP Firestore Console all the info about the other project. Then I wrote the code to make it authomatically and it worked. Honestly I don't know why it didn't worked before, the informations put inside Firestore were the same and the format as well.